# Image does not appear properly

Tags: php, javascript, web

I have added custom code in suffusion-subscription.php to change the image of a Facebook icon when the mouse is hovering on the image.

During initial load, no image shows up. After that mouseHover and mouseOut event shows appropriate images but not on initial load.

The following image shows the issue:

[image]

JavaScript:

```
//preload images:
fb1 = new Image(64,64);
fb1.src = "http://sohamshah.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/follow/Facebook-04.png";
fb2 = new Image(64,64);
fb2.src = "http://sohamshah.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/fb-broken.png";

//image swapping function:
function hiLite(imgDocID, imgObjName, comment) {

document.images[imgDocID].src = eval(imgObjName + ".src");
window.status = comment; return true;
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class='fix'>
    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/sohamshah" class="follow-icon-and-tag" title="RSS">
        <img src="http://sohamshah.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/follow/RSS-13.png" alt="RSS" style='width: 64px; height: 64px;' />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/soham100" onMouseOver="hiLite('fb','fb2','Follow Me on FaceBook')"  onMouseOut="hiLite('fb','fb1','')" class="follow-icon-and-tag" title="Facebook">
        <img name="fb" "src="http://sohamshah.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/follow/Facebook-04.png" alt="Facebook" style='width: 64px; height: 64px;' />
    </a>

  <a href="http://twitter.com/sohamshah" class="follow-icon-and-tag" title="Twitter">
            <img src="http://sohamshah.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/follow/Twitter-08.png" alt="RSS" style='width: 64px; height: 64px;' />
        </a>

   </div>
```

Any help in this matter will be appreciated.

Soham

Comment: You have a stray quotation mark `"` where it says `<img name="fb" "src="http:...` (the quotation to the left of `src`).

Comment: You also shouldn't use `eval`. The expression you have wrapped in `eval` will work on its own without it.

Comment: Oh Gosh, I did not see that. Thanks for the help. It's working perfect now.

Comment: You mean to say, I should keep it like this: //image swapping function:
function hiLite(imgDocID, imgObjName, comment) {

document.images[imgDocID].src = imgObjName + ".src" ;
window.status = comment; return true;
}

Comment: Yes. The line of code that says `eval(imgObjName + ".src")` can just be written as `imageObjName + ".src";` so you are correct.

Comment: @david that wouldn't work. imageObjName is being passed in as a string and just saying `imageObjName + ".src"` would just append `.src` to the name as a string. What he should do, is instead of passing in the name where the function is called, pass in the object. It could then be directly accessed with `imageObjName.src`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes, you're right. I was just scanning the code once and found the eval function. I didn't look any further than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra double quote next to src in the image tag.

Comment: Oh Gosh, I did not see that. Thanks for the help. It's working perfect now.

Comment: @alfasin yes, he beat me by 2 minutes 5 seconds and I didn't see his comment before I posted this response. If he would have posted his comment as an answer, it would have shown to me before I submitted and I wouldn't have submitted a duplicate answer.